# Pgfplots axis width not working

Tags: pgfplots

I created a pgfplots plot on an axis, which I explicitly put at (0cm,0cm) with width=7cm.  I put this inside a larger tikzpicture and drew a rectangle around it `(0cm,0cm) rectangle (7cm,4.2cm)`.  The resulting rectangle is much larger than the plot.  Here is a complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,thick] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (7cm,4.2cm);
\begin{axis}[
    at ={(0cm,0cm)},
    width=7cm,
    height = 4.2cm,
    xmin=-10,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-5,
    ymax=7
]
\addplot [domain=-10:10] {1/2*x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Compiled result:

[image]

How, if possible, can I make the width of the plot actually equal to 7 cm as per the scale in the outer tikzpicture?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Add the option `scale only axis` to the `axis` environment.

Comment: Thanks.  That does seem to work.  Could you explain why that works or point me someplace to read about it?

Comment: Pgfplots comes with a rather extensive manual, which is probably already on your computer (if you can find it).  Mine is located in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\doc\latex\pgfplots.  BTW, the at is reduncant, and there are two other ways of locating the axis box: (rel axis cs: x,y) which can be used inisde the axis environment), and [name=myname] which creates a node (myname) with anchor points north, east, etc which can be used outside the axis environment.

Comment: You are welcome. Please have at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291453/95441) answer to see the difference of the output. And have a look at the `scale only axis` section in the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=272) which is for v1.13 on page 272. If you agree, I will vote to close this question because the comment solved the problem.

Comment: Possibly my question could be edited to be better searchable for future people who had the same problem I had, then the answer along with any useful explanation written before the question is closed.  If this is in fact a duplicate of some other question, I didn't find that other question when I looked for it.